# How to Get the acess token from Google to login Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to implement google sign in in my .Net Standart Xamarin Forms Application.
Here's what've done:

-I used xamarin.auth to authenticate the user, and I get the access token.

-I tried to do:

```
App.MobileService.LoginAsync(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider, accesstoken);
```

And it returned "unauthorized".

From what've searched the acces token that I got above is only for the mobile client, that might be why I'm getting the "unauthorized" error.

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth), I can get an access token for my web app based on the one I already got for my mobile app.

Can anyone tell me how do I get an access token for Azure Mobile Apps based on the one I got for my mobile client?

Comment: Check the solution suggested by taimila in GitHub issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/369 and see if it helps.

Comment: I did, it helped me understand that some things have changed and the team responsible for the Azure Mobile Services are still working on it. I hope they don't take long...